# Java Extends not updating

Tags: java, oop

I am currently working on a hibernate project(EJB and JSF), and i have multiple java classes. The data of parent is being change in the front end with JSF, however, it is not updating in the child class. I need to access the data in the child class to do some calculation. Any Ideas as to how to pass the value of a variable from a parent class to a child class?

Thanks in advance

Example:

Parent class

```
public class parent {

    private String x = "a+";


    public String getx(){
         return x;
    }


    public void setx(String x){
         this.x = x;
    }

}
```

child class

```
public class child extends parent{
    private String z;

    public String getZ(){
        System.out.print(getx());
        return z;
    }
 }
```

main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        parent p = new parent();

        System.out.println("Original" + p.getx());

        p.setx("z");

        System.out.println(" Add z" +p.getx());

        child c = new child();

        System.out.println("child getx" +c.getx());


        p.setx("zZ");
        System.out.println("child getz" +c.getZ());
    }
}
```

result.
Original  a+

Add z z

child getx a+

a+child getz  null

Comment: Please share the relevant code.  There's no chance that what you're describing could happen.  Your error has to be something else.

Comment: @jahroy, this is incorrect.  The code shows exactly what OP is doing wrong.

Comment: @SimonC: jahroy submitted that comment 24 minutes ago; the OP only posted the code 8 minutes ago.  And even then, jahroy is correct: what the OP described is not actually happening, but he's not doing what he described.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you expect here.  Everything is working fine.

In your example, you never call `c.setX`, so why would you expect it to print anything other than `a+`?  `p` refers to a completely different object, and has no relation to `c`.  Therefore, calling `p.setx` will have no effect on `c`.  If you want to set `c.x`, just call `c.setx("z")`.  Do to *polymorphism*, since `child` extends `parent`, you can call methods declared in `parent` on an instance of `child`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting 'z' on two different objects, `c` and `p`.  In order for '`c.getZ()` to return `zZ`, you would need to call `c.setx("zZ")`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, in the application that i am working on the front end is interacting with "parent". and i need to get the updated value from "child". And when i call getx from child it is returning "a+" instead of the updated value

Comment: @user1817081 - You misunderstand the concept of inheritance.  Just because class C extends class P, it doesn't mean that every instance of C will get updated whenever any instance of P does (thank goodness).

Comment: OK, I was able to get what I was looking to do by making the variable in parent static so I can access it from main. Thanks!